How to sum the max metric values by grouping in Sumologic
Using queries for a metric I use, I am trying to sum all of the Max values grouped by a field task_id.
I have tried a few variations, e.g.
metric=flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_KafkaProducer_record_send_total namespace="flink" deployment="flink-job" | sum by task_id, and none gives as a result the sum of a specific task_id Max values.
This screenshot is to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. For the marked task_id (starts with 6cdc), I would like to have one row with the sum of all max values: 8800+8669+0+6217+7277=30963.
How can it be done?


Try:
... | max by task_id, task_name | sum by task_id

(note, I am just guessing the task_name field in the first aggregation based on your screenshot)
The somewhat informal explanation is that the Min | Max | Latest | Avg | ... columns you can see in the Time Series tab are not coming from your query. They are extra aggregate information displayed on top of your query results.
Thus, if you | sum by task_id you never take the max of anything.

Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Sumo Logic.
